# C# alternative to VB code

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have this VB code

```
 Public Function InitMeridDataType() As MeridDataType
        Dim OutData As MeridDataType
        With OutData
            .NumCurves = 0
            Erase .CurveData
        End With
        Return OutData
    End Function
```

I converted this code into C# using [Telerik Online Tool](http://converter.telerik.com/)

The C# code is

```
 public static MeridDataType InitMeridDataType()
        {
            MeridDataType OutData = default(MeridDataType);
            var _with1 = OutData;
            _with1.NumCurves = 0;
            _with1.CurveData = null;
            return OutData;
        }
```

**MeridDataType** is defined in VB as

```
Public Structure MeridDataType
        Dim NumCurves As Short
        Dim CurveData() As CurveDataType
    End Structure
```

I feel like there is something seriously wrong with the C# code. Shouldn't it be returning **_with1** ?

A version of which I have written is

```
public static MeridDataType InitMeridDataType()
            {
                MeridDataType OutData = default(MeridDataType);
                //var _with1 = OutData;
                OutData .NumCurves = 0;
                OutData .CurveData = null;
                return OutData;
            }
```

any leads ?

Comment: I can't find any construction where this code makes sense. If `MeridDataType` is a reference type, then this code should always generate a `NullReferenceException`. If `MeridDataType` is a value type, then the original `With` block should have been rejected by the compiler, since you can only *read* members and invoke methods within such a `With` block.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I agree. Some simple tests show that the said tool does not care about the (semantic) validity of the code. It will happily convert a NRE-causing code without issues. So, I guess the original VB.NET code had "issues" as well, that were "properly" converted ;-)

Comment: The whole method is pointless in c#, this is what the default constructor of the struct would do anyways.

Comment: You got what you paid for.  It will work anyway.

Answer (score 3):

> I feel like there is something seriously wrong with the C# code.

I agree. `MeridDataType` is defined as a value type, so attempting to modify `OutData` through a copy `_with1` will not have the intended effect: An unmodified `OutData` will be returned.

If all you need to do is set some properties on a data object, this is about as simple as it gets in C#:

```
public static MeridDataType InitMeridDataType()
{
   return new MeridDataType()  // the parentheses are actually optional
   {
       NumCurves = 0,
       CurveData = null
   };
}
```

(By the way: Explicitly setting `NumCurves` and `CurveData` to "null values" is not actually necessary. This is already done implicitly through the default constructor, which initializes the underlying memory to "all zeroes", so resetting these properties has no additional effect! Nevertheless, this *may* be a good idea because it makes explicit what your values should be initialized to.)

---

#### P.S.: `new T()` or `default(T)`?

TL;DR: Use `new T(…)` for creating `T` instances, not `default(T)`… even for `struct`s.

Getting a fresh instance of some type `T` is properly done via `new T()`. Unlike `default(T)`, this states your intent clearly, and has the benefit of always doing what you want:

- For value types (`struct`s) only, C#'s `default(T)` *is* equivalent to the `new T()` default constructor: both give you a instance of the value type that has its underlying memory initialized to "all zeroes". But it's a sneaky way of creating a fresh instance, and not very transparent. Better reserve the use of `default(T)` for situations when you don't know the actual type `T`, e.g. inside a generic method.
- For reference types (e.g. `class`, `interface`), `default(T)` will return a `null` reference, so subsequently accessing `T` will produce an exception.

Comment: Thanks :) but is the way mentioed by @Kurakura88 also fine ?

Comment: @Apoorv, yes, the way Kurakura88 suggest will work fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Reference to default: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx.
If MeridDataType is a struct, then your code should work fine. If it is a class, then it would be better to instantiate with default constructor.

```
public static MeridDataType InitMeridDataType()
{
   MeridDataType OutData = new MeridDataType();
   OutData.NumCurves = 0;
   OutData.CurveData = null;
   return OutData;
}
```

Comment: Assuming that the VB.NET code was logically correct and not buggy, it appears that `MeridDataType` would be a value type (`struct`), so `default(MeridDataType)` does not equal `null`. It equals a `MeridDataType` that has its underlying memory bits  zeroed out.

Comment: I'll take your word

Comment: @kurakura88 MeridDataType is a struct . Can you double check and let me know if I could continue using Default ?

Comment: default should be fine as everyone said, as long as it is a struct

Comment: @Apoorv: If `MeridDataType` is a value type (`struct`), `default(MeridDataType)` is equivalent to `new MeridDataType()`, but it is not a good idea. Use the more explicit `new MeridDataType()` instead. Reserve `default(T)` for cases when `new T()` is not available, such as in a generic method where you don't know what `T` might be.

Answer (score -1):

OutData and _with1 are the same object, so it really doesn't match which you return.

Comment: As I say in a comment, I can't make sense of this construction. *If* `MeridDataType` is a reference type, the variable is effectively assigned `null` (via `default`) and then has its `NumCurves` property set - which should always generate an exception.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I dont know how to fix things up. What do you want me to do with default? shall I remove it and use new operator ? as far as I understand , default initializes the elements to their initial value

Comment: Neil : `OutData` and `_with1` are _not_ the same object, since `MediaDataType` is a value type (a `Structure`). This line: `var _with1 = OutData;` makes a shallow copy of `OutData`, meaning we now have **two** different structs.